# Directory listing for icons and image folders

Tags: apache, configuration

I am testing web application on Apache server, which allows to list directories such as https://192.168.100.00:443/icons/ and https://192.168.100.00:443/images/. This directories contains only images.

Should I recommend to disallow directory listing for all directories as a best practice?

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on what the owner of the server wishes to use the directory listing for - there may be a need to have it on.

That said, in many cases directory listing should be turned off if there is no need for it to be on, this is because its a potential vulnerability that could be easily mitigated